# Binding Button Background not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hei,

I m tryng to bind Button background to a property in my viewmodel. Here's what ia have:

```
private bool _LoginSuccessful;
public bool LoginSuccessful
{
    get { return _LoginSuccessful; }
    set
    {
        _LoginSuccessful = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("LoginSuccessful");
        RaisePropertyChanged("ButtonBackground");
    }
}

public Brush ButtonBackground
{
    get
    {
        return LoginSuccessful ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.LimeGreen;
    }
}
```

And xaml looks like this:

```
<Button Content="{Binding CurrentStatus}" 
        Background="{Binding ButtonBackground}" 
        Width="300"Margin="2" />
```

Problem is that the button background never gets changed.. Its white when i open the application and afther changing `LoginSuccessful` it still stays white.

**EDIT:**

Im using MahApps.Metro in my application and the button style comes from here:
https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Buttons.xaml

Can this mix some stuff up why my binding isnt working?

**SOLUTION:**

My problem didnt have anything to do with Mahapps.Metro. It was just the reason i was using `Brush` and not `SolidColorBrush`. Here's working code from view model:

```
public SolidColorBrush ButtonBackground
{
    get
    {
        return LoginSuccessful ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LimeGreen);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `DataContext` set to your view model? Your button should be either LimeGreen or Red and not White. Is `CurrentStaus` part of the same view model? If yes does it display fine?

Comment: Yes, `CurrentStatus` is part of same view model and is updated fine if i change the value.

Comment: In that case do you use some custom template for `Button`? If yes can you add it to your question?

Comment: Edited original post.

Comment: In such case I can only advise you to look at your application via [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) or [WPF Inspector](https://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/) - probably something will became clear.

Comment: Yes, it gets called.